# Numpy or pandas: test whether upper or lower bound is reached in array / series, and which is reached first

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a pandas Series.

I need to check whether a lower or upper bound is reached within the series.

In the event of both lower and upper bound being reached, I need to know **which is reached first**.

I can use the `.max()` and `.min()` functions to determine whether one of the bounds has been reached:

```
def upper_bound_reached(series, upper_bound):
    return series.max() >= upper_bound

def lower_bound_reached(series, lower_bound):
    return series.min() <= lower_bound
```

The problem I'm having is working out which is reached first

```
if upper_bound_reached(series, ub) and lower_bound_reached(series, lb):
    # work out which bound is reached first
```

What is the most idiomatic way of achieving this?

### Some graphs showing what I'm looking for:

**No bound reached - return NONE:**

[image: no bound hit]

---

**Only upper bound reached - return UPPER:**

[image: upper bound hit first]

---

**Both bounds reached, lower bound first - return LOWER:**

[image: lower bound hit first]

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = pd.Series(np.sin(np.arange(0, 7, .1)))
upper_bound = 0.5
lower_bound = -0.5

filtered = s[(s >= upper_bound) | (s <= lower_bound)]

first_crossing = None
if not filtered.empty:
    first_crossing = 'UPPER' if filtered.index[0] >= upper_bound else 'LOWER'

>>> first_crossing
'UPPER'
```

Comment: So simple! Thank you!